# What is the difference between "Grippe" and "Männergrippe"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Sometimes people say

*"Er hat Grippe."*

and sometimes they say

*"Er hat Männergrippe."*

When to use which? Where is the difference?

Comment: It's a joke referring to men to be more snivelling in contrast to women.

Comment: This should be an answer

Comment: It is a loan-translation (calque) of the English phrase "man flu".

Comment: @fdb do you have a source to back this up? I find it quite feasible that both terms developed separately, and even if they didn't I see no reason to believe that the translation went in this direction and not the other.

Comment: “Männergrippe” is just a cold/flu where the man is super whiny and makes jokes like this one: “While giving birth to a child a woman can get a glimpse of the pain and agony that a man suffers through while having a mild cold.”

Comment: @DreamConspiracy: The oldest citation in English is from 1999 (https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113198?redirectedFrom=man+flu#eid1260352850). The oldest citation in German is from 2015 (https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=zeit;q=M%C3%A4nnergrippe)

Comment: Just a side note, „Grippe“ flu as a rather serious illness is often used for normal cold symptoms („Erkältung“) in colloquial terms. Not sure if this is the same in English?

Comment: @eckes: When Germans say “Grippe” they usually mean “grippaler Infekt”, so I think that this is also the case with “Männergrippe”.

Comment: "Männerschnupfen" seems to be the more familiar term in this context. "Schnupfen" is definitely a harmless and mild disorder, but "Grippe" can mean influenza which is a serious disease  - even for women ..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like πάντα ῥεῖ wrote, "Männergrippe" is not a real illness but a joke.

This joke bases on the assumption, men are more histrionics if they get ill than women.

In some comedy the man is shown helpless and whining because he has a cold. The woman instead organizes whole household, children and her job with a broken leg.

So the use of "Männergrippe" let you know, your conversational partner has doubts about the severity of the illness.

Then basing on the mimic you can see, if this person is joking, or really upset about this overstatement of the ill/not so ill person.

In difference "Grippe" is a real disease. It spreads fast. Sometimes, if it is wide spread one talks about "Grippewelle", and there exists vaccinations against it.

Comment: When someone shows signs of *Männergrippe*, people often comment on it with a healthy dose of *mimimi*.

Comment: The problem with *Männergrippe* is the same as with *Verschwörungstheorie*. The word itself presupposes that there is no *real* disease (infection, or whatever), or that there is no *real* problem (criminal activity different from what official sources say). It makes discourse about factually existing issues, or about problems with official statements, difficult if not impossible.

Comment: FWIW, the actual word "grippe" is also used in English as a synonym for the flu, though it is somewhat archaic. The Spanish cognate, *gripa*, is in somewhat more common use.

Comment: It should perhaps be mentioned that *Männergrippe* can also be understood as a modern revenge for the older *Frauenleiden*, which originally means issues with health or well-being especially (and exclusively) of women, but may have also an undertone of "not to be taken seriously".

Comment: @Philipp But what is the healthy dose of mimimi? And the LD50? And are women resistant?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann [Frauenleiden](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frauenleiden) are/were real problems/illnesses, and as a concept arguably more or less outdated. *Männergrippe* is just derogatory sexism – 'for a change' directed against men.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: the healthy dose is the same as the one you need to make a well perceived joke. Thus the LD50 is the treshold wether the one with *Männergrippe* is able to deliberate or only able to punch...

Answer (score 28):

The word *"Männergrippe"* is used mockingly by women who perceive that men complain and whinge too much when they have a flu or simply a cold. The expression is not exclusively German, you can find *"man flu"* in English language dictionaries:

> **man flu**
>
> [..] (informal, humorous)
>
> a cold or similar minor illness that a man catches and treats as if it were flu or something more serious
>
> - Greg was off sick with man flu, according to his wife.

(Source: [Oxford Learners' Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/man-flu?q=man+flu))

Actually, it seems that men suffer indeed more from a flu than women. This may be due to the way in which the sexual hormones testosterone and oestrogen affect the immune response (see [Infektionen: "Männergrippe" ist kein Mythos](https://www.ndr.de/ratgeber/gesundheit/Infektionen-Maennergrippe-ist-kein-Mythos,immunsystem106.html) or [Man flu is real because oestrogen protects women from the influenza virus](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/health-fitness/body/man-flu-is-real-because-oestrogen-protects-women-from-the-influe/)).

In a more scientific article: [The science behind “man flu”](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kyle_Sue/publication/321691886_The_science_behind_man_flu/links/5a2b31bb0f7e9b63e538cf72/The-science-behind-man-flu.pdf) by author Kyle Sue you can read:

> The concept of man flu, as commonly defined, is potentially
>   unjust. Men may not be exaggerating symptoms but have weaker
>   immune responses to viral respiratory viruses, leading to greater
>   morbidity and mortality than seen in women.

Overall, evidence seems to be limited.

Comment: It is not only used by women.

Comment: Note that "Männergrippe" just like "Grippe" itself may be used for all kinds of colds and other typical Winter respiratory infections, not just the actual *Grippe* (influenza) itself, which is a serious, sometimes lethal (the lethality rate of the yearly "Grippewelle" is around 10%) illness.

Comment: True, it’s common to say that someone has the Grippe while they only have a “grippaler Infekt” / “Erkältung” (the latter translates to “the common cold”), the actual _influenza_ (this word is understood to disambiguate) is (thankfully much more rare).

Comment: I would add that, in contrast to the first sentence, "Männergrippe" is also used in the case of a common cold or other minor trouble.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other entries here. I can say that when I have a "Grippe" I often refer to it as a "Männergrippe" to tell others that I am very very sick. In a joking way and with additions in "please call an ambulance for me" and so on. Very much joking and "mimimi". If a guy tells another guy he has a "Männergrippe" we often ask If we should call an ambulance too (jokingly).